# ¿Como hacer una calculadora utilizando JavaFX?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

Tengo un trabajo escolar en el cual debo realizar una calculadora con JavaFX
La interfaz grafica ya la tengo lista pero es la parte del controlador de la calculadora que no me funciona
cuando realizo una suma funciona perfectamente pero cuando intento realizar otro tipo de operaciones como la resta es cuando me da resultados erroneos y no se que podria estar mal

```
public class FMXLController implements Initializable {
    
    
    private double n1;
    private double n2;
    private double resultado;
    private byte contador=0;
    private char operador;

    public double getN1() {
        return n1;
    }

    public void setN1(double n1) {
        this.n1 = n1;
    }

    public double getN2() {
        return n2;
    }

    public void setN2(double n2) {
        this.n2 = n2;
    }

    public byte getContador() {
        return contador;
    }

    public void setContador(byte contador) {
        this.contador = contador;
    }

    public char getOperador() {
        return operador;
    }

    public void setOperador(char operador) {
        this.operador = operador;
    }
    

    @FXML
    private Label lblPantalla;
    @FXML
    private Button btnAc;
    @FXML
    private Button btnMasMenos;
    @FXML
    private Button btnSiete;
    @FXML
    private Button btnPorcentaje;
    @FXML
    private Button btnOcho;
    @FXML
    private Button btnDiv;
    @FXML
    private Button btnNueve;
    @FXML
    private Button btnMulti;
    @FXML
    private Button btnCuatro;
    @FXML
    private Button btnCinco;
    @FXML
    private Button btnSeis;
    @FXML
    private Button btnMenos;
    @FXML
    private Button btnUno;
    @FXML
    private Button btnCero;
    @FXML
    private Button btnDos;
    @FXML
    private Button btnTres;
    @FXML
    private Button btnPunto;
    @FXML
    private Button btnMas;
    @FXML
    private Button btnIgual;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

    @FXML
    private void clicAc(ActionEvent event) {
        calcular("AC");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicMasMenos(ActionEvent event) {
        calcular("+/-");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicSiete(ActionEvent event) {
        lblPantalla.setText(lblPantalla.getText()+"7");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicPorcentaje(ActionEvent event) {
        calcular("%");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicOcho(ActionEvent event) {
        lblPantalla.setText(lblPantalla.getText()+"8");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicDiv(ActionEvent event) {
        calcular("/");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicNueve(ActionEvent event) {
        lblPantalla.setText(lblPantalla.getText()+"9");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicPor(ActionEvent event) {
        calcular("*");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicCuatro(ActionEvent event) {
        lblPantalla.setText(lblPantalla.getText()+"4");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicCinco(ActionEvent event) {
        lblPantalla.setText(lblPantalla.getText()+"5");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicSeis(ActionEvent event) {
        lblPantalla.setText(lblPantalla.getText()+"6");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicMenos(ActionEvent event) {
        calcular("-");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicUno(ActionEvent event) {
        lblPantalla.setText(lblPantalla.getText()+"1");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicCero(ActionEvent event) {
        lblPantalla.setText(lblPantalla.getText()+"0");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicDos(ActionEvent event) {
        lblPantalla.setText(lblPantalla.getText()+"2");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicTres(ActionEvent event) {
        lblPantalla.setText(lblPantalla.getText()+"3");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicPunto(ActionEvent event) {
        lblPantalla.setText(lblPantalla.getText()+".");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicMas(ActionEvent event) {
        calcular("+");
    }

    @FXML
    private void clicIgual(ActionEvent event) {
        calcular(String.valueOf(this.operador));
        
        lblPantalla.setText(String.valueOf(this.resultado));
    }
    
    
    public void calcular(String operador){
        contador++;
        
        if(contador==1){
        n1=Double.parseDouble(lblPantalla.getText());
        }
        else if(contador==2){
        n2=Double.parseDouble(lblPantalla.getText());
        
            resultado=0.0;           
            
            switch(operador){
            case "+":
                resultado=n1+n2;
                break;
            case "-":
                resultado=n1-n2;
                break;
            case "*":
                resultado=n1*n2;
                break;
            case "/":
                resultado=n1/n2;
                break;
            case "%":
                resultado=n1%n2;
                break;
            case "AC":
                resultado=0.0;
                n1=0;
                break;
                
        }
            n1=resultado;
            contador=1;
        }
            lblPantalla.setText("");
            this.operador=operador.charAt(0);
    }
}
```